# Deleting a resource using POST method instead of DELETE Method in REST API

Tags: api-testing, postman, system-software-testing

I was taking some online course to learn API testing. As per my understanding We can use

POST: to add the items (e.g., adding a new book in the library)

GET: to view/ see the items (e.g., see the books in the library)

DELETE: to delete the items (e.g., delete the book from the library)

But there, the tutor used POST method to delete the book using the id

{
"id" : "abc"
}
and the book deleted successfully.

It was something new for me. Can you please elaborate why we use post instead of delete?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question to ask as you are beginning your journey.

You need to understand the purpose of each HTTP Method (also known as HTTP Verbs).

The purpose of `POST` is to update a resource by sending data to the server/database via the API. `POST` doesn't care what data is being sent.

It could be:

- adding new data
- updating existing data
- deleting existing data

The question now is, are we using the correct method semantically?

The answer is no. Just because you can use `POST` for deleting data doesn't mean you should. The proper method is `DELETE`. Why?

First, code readability and clarity. If I'm reading code and see `POST`, I think of an update to the data, not the deletion of the data. Having it delete data is not easily understandable, as it takes more time to understand what is going on. If I saw this in a code review, I wouldn't approve it until it was fixed (to use `DELETE`). It makes it easier for other developers to understand and to yourself over time!

Using `DELETE` is more semantically correct by design. You understand it immediately. You may still question why something needs to be deleted, but you understand what is occurring.

You need to understand some other technical aspects. The terms *idempotent*, *safe*, *cacheable* often come up.

**Idempotent:** refers to the intention or intended effect of a single request to the server. In other words, a single request should have the same result as making many identical requests. As previously noted, `POST` is not intended to be used for a delete and is NOT idempotent by design. A post by nature is intended to have different results since it's about updating. Whereas, `DELETE` is intended for removal of data and IS idempotent since you can't delete something more than 1 time!

**Safe:** refers to an HTTP method having the operation be read-only. `DELETE` and `POST` are considered *unsafe* by design because they remove data or update data, aka, not read-only since they alter the state of the data.

**Cacheable:** refers to an HTTP method where the response can be stored and used later. `DELETE` is NOT cacheable by design. You don't want to store/cache this response to use it later; you can't use it later since the data you're operating on is no longer there! Going back to idempotent, you only delete data once! `POST` IS cacheable as you might want to use the response for a future operation (such as an update). If you use `POST` to delete data, it can lead to bugs and errors occurring because of the caching ability. From a testing perspective, you want to prevent bugs and errors, so using HTTP Methods correctly means preventing bugs/errors!

So, why was the instructor using `POST` to delete? This could be due to laziness, just needing to do something quickly, or maybe they don't understand the technicality of HTTP Methods, which would cause me to question why they are teaching.